# How to blockall requests to /actuator aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

We have a springboot application running as a single instance( there is no Loadbalancer) on aws elastic beanstalk.
The question is how  to protect/block the /actuator path (only admins) could access it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can't without a load balancer.

With ALB you can configure some settings to restrict access, but not with custom authentication.